# Unexplained Apple Mach-O liner warning error

Tags: xcode, admob, linker-errors

Yesterday i integrated Google's Admobs fine into my Xcode 6.1 project. Everything worked. Today i open Xcode and i receive the following errors...

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Marco/Desktop/SpaceAlien copy 1/Space

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LAlien'

ld: library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds

It's 2 yellow warning errors and the RED error doesn't let me build project = GoogleAdMobAds

So I read in Project Navigator for libGoogleAdMobAds.a in target membership to unclick and then click back the check. That works and project builds. However, when i close project open it again, I get the same error. How do I make this error remove permanently? Also, for the ld: warning: directory not found errors I went to build setting then library search paths and i CAN'T delete anything, don't know what to do. Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Marco/Desktop/SpaceAlien copy 1/Space
```

Problem is because the path contains spaces. Try using quotes with the path: "Users/Marco/Desktop/SpaceAlien copy 1/Space"

or you can use escape "\" character to "fix" the path:

```
Users/Marco/Desktop/SpaceAlien\ copy\ 1/Space
```

Comment: I did the " marks at end and beginning and tried \ and even tried making no spaces but still all errors are shown and nothing changes. For library not found for -lGoogleAdMobAds error, how do I add a library Search Paths build settings?

Comment: Here is a screenshot: http://tagtaxa.com/download/sp.jpg .Be advised that the path above might not be complete since compiler split your path on spaces, just escape all spaces as it is in the path above.

Comment: I completed deleted everything in library search paths and the 2 warning errors go away. However, when I close the project then reopen it again i receive the errors again and the/Users/Marco/Desktop/SpaceAlien copy 1/Space appears in library search paths as if i never deleted it. How do I make it stay deleted forever?